# How to encrypt an XML file in Ubuntu with openssl using the public key?

Tags: linux, openssl

can any one able to tell me how to encrypt and decrypt an xml file using openssl.
i can able to create privatekey using the linux command
 openssl genrsa -out private.pem 1024 and got my private key as private.pem
also i create public key using
 openssl rsa -in private.pem -out public.pem -outform PEM -pubout got my public key as public.pem
now wat i want is i want to encrypt the xml file using this public key and again want to decrypt using my private key....please help me...
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is this:

1. If you have a PEM encoded key:

   ```
   openssl pkeyutl -encrypt -in FileToEncrypt -out EncryptedData.enc -inkey ThePathToYourPublicKey -keyform PEM
   ```

   If you have a DER encoded key:

   ```
   openssl pkeyutl -encrypt -in FileToEncrypt -out EncryptedData.enc -inkey ThePathToYourPublicKey -keyform DER
   ```
2. You then decrypt with:

   ```
   openssl pkeyutl -decrypt -in EncryptedData.enc -out DecryptedFile -inkey ThePathToYourPrivateKey
   ```

For more information about this you can consult openssl's [pkeyutil documentation](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/pkeyutl.html).

If you want to use S/MIME packaging (a standard used to encrypt/decrypt/sign e-mails), see openssl's [smime documentation](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/smime.html).

Answer (score 0):

Encrypt with public key:

```
openssl rsautl -encrypt -inkey public.pem -pubin -in xml.file -out encrypted.enc
```

Decrypt with private key:

```
openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey private.pem -in encrypted.enc -out xml.txt
```